# Best way to capture a quickly incrementing/rotating value to confirm it passed a threshold

Tags: android, kotlin, conditional-statements, android-jetpack-compose

I have a variable whose value can change as frequently as the device frame-rate. Now, actually it is an angle, but perhaps can be thought of as a regularly incrementing value. What I wish, is to calculate how many 360 loops have been made. I have a Composable, which I have hooked up to this value. So the user is basically rotating an indicator, and I update the value based on the angle. Now, I already have a system put in place which performs a calculation on the indicator position and renders an angle ranging from 0 to 359 (well 360 actually, but non-inclusive). So, now if the user is spinning the indicator, I want to know when he actually hits the 0f Angle. I tried it with a conditional but this does not work if the user is going even at a reasonable speed. He must be incredibly slow in order to capture that value.

Here's a sample

```
val angle = ...//Already Got this Value
if(angle == 0f) { /*One cycle Complete*/ } // But this is not detected mostly
```

Now, remember that this is Compose, so we must take recompositions into account. I have tried with a list, by storing some of the latest values of the variable, but it just rotates too fast. All the values end up being the same, unless the size is crazy like 500 or so.

Can my approach be better? Any known way of accomplishing this without changing the approach. Basically any help would be appreciable.

Comment: This isn’t Compose-specific. It’s input-limited and you would have the same issue on pretty much any OS. Input is only reported at some maximum rate. You need to record the value each frame and compare it to the value from the previous frame to see if it has crossed the 0 threshold since the previous frame. If the user can rotate it in both directions, you might also need to be tracking the direction moved from the past two frames to determine which direction it is moving.

Comment: And I can get the value every frame, how?

Comment: Check the edit, please.

Comment: I don’t know Compose or I’d write an answer with a suggested approach.

Comment: That's completely fine, thank you for the effort anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing and it works at any given speed

```
var cycles by remember { mutableStateOf(0) } // Holds cycles state
        val startCheck by mutableStateOf(angle in 300..360) //The Hot-Zone for Active Monitoring


        LaunchedEffect(angle) { //This executes every time angle changes, i.e, at frame rate
            if (startCheck) { //Only if indicator is in the hot zone
                if (angle <300 ) cycles++ //Increment the Cycles
            }
        }
```